# Tensorflow runs out of memory even though I am using 4 GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, out-of-memory

My specs first:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698 v4 @ 2.20GHz
GPUs: 4x Tesla V100 16 GB
RAM: 256 GB DDR4
```

I want to train a network using code from someone else ([Click](https://github.com/Richardzhangxx/AMR-Benchmark/blob/main/RML2018/LSTM2/main.py). I am training on the same dataset of size ~20 GB (RML2018.01 Dataset). I am using the exact same training parameters with a batch size of 400 but for testing purposes just 1 epoche. The network has 202,776 parameters and whenever I want to train I get a "not enough memory" error. I manipulated the above code by changing `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"` to `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,3"` and changing the following lines:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = culstm.LSTMModel(weights=None,input_shape=[1024,2], classes=24)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

to support my quad GPU setup. There is also a [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/402ab407cf70b542818c8b0f6c4736d3) of the error log. With GPU and RAM load during training [here](https://gyazo.com/67cf08e25e670b97ae7defee64d3e315).

Things I tried:

- Adding `os.environ["TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR"] = "cuda_malloc_async"`
- Adding

```
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

- Freeing GPU Cache

All 4 graphics cards are recognized inside the docker container using `nvidia-smi`. Furthermore, when I half the dataset, the error does not occur. And I also tried a batch size of 8 with the full data set which also works, **but** both options are not viable to me because I want to reproduce the results from the research done before. From the code linked above, it seems like this model was trained on only one GPU. So 4 GPUs should be enough (hopefully).

I suspect that somehow it does not use the VRAM of the other GPUs correctly, even though it allocates
memory on all GPUs when I start the training. If I use the flag: `os.environ["TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR"] = "cuda_malloc_async"` the VRAM that is taken/allocated by tensorflow is approx 15GB + 3.5 GB * 3 = 25.5 GB of 64 GB total VRAM. In addition to that, the total RAM usage is never really above 100 GB, so something doesn't add up here. (As seen in the above screenshot)

Comment: Your GPUs only have 16GB of RAM.  You can see in your log that you were already using 15.7GB, so adding anything more puts you over the limit.  Spreading across multiple GPUs doesn't reduce the memory load.  They're all doing a part of the job.  You can either reduce the workload or buy GPUs with more RAM.

Comment: @TimRoberts Why doesn't it reduce the memory load if I spread it across multiple GPUs? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It is not like that your model gets partioned across multiple GPUs (model parallelism), instead a single or multiple GPUs load the model architecture as a independently (data parallel) see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/distributed-parallel-training-data-parallelism-and-model-parallelism-ec2d234e3214#:~:text=Model%20parallelism%20shards%20a%20model,wraps%20it%20with%20minimal%20changes.). The former is much more difficult as more things are required to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Reduce the batch size, 400 is probably too large.

Comment: @null But the dataset should be splitted among the GPUs and not loaded entirely. At least that's what I read how data parallelism works. The model itself is really small < 1 GB.

Comment: If you meant to load 400 over 4 GPUs, try passing 100 as batchsize, this is the batch size effectively be loaded on each GPU most probably. Another trick is to use batch size as powers of 2; while the real effect of this is unknown, it is common choice, try 64 or 128.